# Data Structure, Database, and API for Rendering Family Tree in PixiJS

Tags: database, data-structures

#### Background

I have obtained an ancestry book that contains family history data printed in the late 90s. The book comprises potentially thousands of records.

I attempted to reach out to the author, but unfortunately, he passed away in the year 2000, and his children do not have any digital materials related to the subject matter. Furthermore, the publisher went out of business in 2008, and I am doubtful that they have any means to provide any relevant materials at this time.

I want to build a system that can render a family history book in client-side using PixiJS, allowing family members to browse and drag the content on the canvas to view the family's history without requiring the physical book.

To achieve this, I plan to extract the data using image-to-text APIs such as AWS Rekognition or Azure Computer Vision. While I have sufficient knowledge to design and build this image-to-text extraction functionality and rendering of display object in PixiJS, I am uncertain about the best data structure to use for efficiently storing and querying the extracted data.

Although I don't anticipate having many users, and will likely limit access to only a small set of family members, I am motivated to create this system as a legacy that my future self and children can enjoy and learn from. It's important to me to preserve and share our family's history in a way that is both engaging and accessible, and I believe that this project can accomplish that goal

Therefore, I'm looking for suggestion on data structure that is best suited for this purpose.

### Choice Data Structure

I've considered a couple model that could be suitable for this purpose.

##### Adjacency List Model

Where each row represents a person, ID for parent(s).

- Simple but probably inefficient for querying deep trees
- Not effective for individuals with unknown parents, or only list more distant relationship (i.e. John is 16th gen ancestor of 18th gen Doe, where 17th are unknown)
- Not suitable for "circular marrage" or individuals with multiple wives/concubines

##### Nested Set model

- Represents hierarchy as a set of intervals
- Each person has 2 numbers of lower and upper bounds, which contains all children
- Simpler than other models in terms of querying complexity
- Still subject to the same issues as Adjacency List Model

##### Closure table model

Uses 2 tables to represent the relationships.

- One table contains just name and ID, while the other contains all possible paths between 2 people
- More complicated and requires more complex queries, such as table join queries on multiple people
- Allows for more flexible querying of more complicated relationships

### Choice of Database

The three models I have considered are SQL-based. MySQL or SQLite would likely suffice for my purposes. However, I have also considered other options:

- Document-oriented database: Limited knowledge, but may provide an easy way to link people in each document.
- Graph-oriented database (e.g. Neo4j): Not much knowledge, but could also be suitable for the purpose.
- Fully Managed solution: GraphQL (with AWS AppSync) could manage the NoSQL database automatically, however, this costs money and would likely change the architecture to be fully cloud base instead of having a simple Node server to provides data.

### Choice of API

If a SQL-like solution/data structure is suggested, then a simple REST API on a ubuntu docker image should be sufficient for accessing the data.

However, it's also possible for the frontend to sit in a S3 bucket and interact with the data via GraphQL, which can simplify the process and ignore all server side hosting logic.

While this decision is largely based on the data models suggested in the previous questions, I'm also open to additional suggestions that can help me achieve my goals for this project

Comment: You might be focusing too much on the back end side of things. It's a family book with content that is probably mostly static and can be hardcoded into your frontend code. Most of the work for this will be in creating a visually appealing and interactive experience for your users.

Comment: And hosting a REST API and a database isn't free. It will be easier to redeploy static frontend code with updated information since updates to your data are likely fairly rare.